# How to choose Qt installation?

Tags: debian, environment-variables, qt

I've built (`configure`, `make`, `make install`) Qt 5.4.2 from sources on my Debian 7.8 x64. Now I try to build `Qt Creator`, but my system is unable to locate this specific Qt build.

Firstly, I tried to set `$QTDIR` and `$PATH`, but it didn't work. Then, I have read that [it is necessary to use `qtchooser`.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820054/selecting-qt5-using-qtchooser) So, this is what I have so far:

```
ber@mydeb:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser$ qtchooser -l
4
5
@5
@qt5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

Initially, there was no `default` conf, but I've created it using the following:

```
ber@mydeb:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser$ sudo nano default.conf
```

with the text:

```
QT_SELECT="5"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/"
```

After this, my system still used a wrong Qt installation
(from the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder),
which does not contain a working Qt installation.

Then, I tried to set `QT_SELECT=default`, then `QT_SELECT=5` and here is what I have now:

```
qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="qt5"
QTTOOLDIR="QT_SELECT="5""
QTLIBDIR="QTTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/bin""
```

i.e., `QTTOOLDIR=variable` is wrong and here is an error displayed when I try to use `qmake`:

```
qmake -v
qmake: could not exec 'QT_SELECT="5"/qmake': No such file or directory
```

What should I do to choose the correct Qt installation (the one installed to the `/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/` folder)?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by:

1. Restore my system state (I'm on a virtual machine) to the moment where I had not yet edit qtchooser's conf files
2. Run `qtchooser -print-env`, which had showed that `QT_SELECT="qt5"`
3. Opened `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser$ sudo nano qt5.conf`, where I had seen two strings without variable names:

   `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
4. Changed them to:

   `/usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/bin
    /usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/`
5. And now I have:

   `qmake -v
    QMake version 3.0
    Using Qt version 5.4.1 in /usr/local/Qt-5.4.1/lib`